# Giving a model attributes methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Song` model has a `lyrics` text attribute. Since new lines are `\n`-separated in my lyrics, I often find myself doing this in my views to make the lyrics HTML-friendly:

```
@song.lyrics.strip.gsub(/\n/, "\n<br />")
```

I'm repeating the `gsub` logic all over my application, and, worse still, I can't change the format in which I store my lyrics without touching everywhere I tried printing them as HTML.

I'd like to abstract this so that I can write this in my views:

```
@song.lyrics.to_html
```

So that the `strip.gsub(/\n/, "\n<br />")` logic is present in only one place in my application (in the `to_html` method).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the exact `@song.lyrics.to_html` syntax and you don't want to create a Lyrics model, you can add a singleton method to the string returned by the `lyrics` method:

```
class Song
  def lyrics
    str = read_attribute(:lyrics)
    def str.to_html
      strip.gsub(/\n/, "\n<br />")
    end
    str
  end
end
```

However, this is not really a great design. For something more re-usable you might want to write a module with a `to_html` method like this:

```
module HtmlFormatter
  def to_html(attribute)
    send(attribute).strip.gsub(/\n/, "\n<br />")
  end
end
```

If you `include HtmlFormatter` in your Song model you can call the method like this:

```
@song.to_html(:lyrics)
```

So it doesn't follow your desired syntax exactly, but I think it's a better design.

You might also want to consider a separate Lyrics model which could have all kinds of features, but this might be too heavy for your application.

Comment: Definitely don't want a lyrics model. The `HtmlFormatter` module sounds good, but it conflicts with acts_as_markdown (which mixes in a separate `to_html` method for markdown attributes)

Comment: Why not just use markdown? It will give you the line breaks you want, right? If you don't want to use it, you'll obviously have to rename the method...

Comment: Also, won't your lyrics method return `nil` as written? (Needs to return `str` after the method definition)

Comment: "It will give you the line breaks you want, right?" -- no; markdown (somewhat confusingly) ignores single newlines

Comment: Didn't know that--I've always worked with Textile (RedCloth gem). And yes, you're right that my method needs to return `str`--I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Since is a view-related issue, you can place your to_html method on the ApplicationHelper module

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def to_html(str)
    str.strip.gsub(/\n/, "\n<br />")
  end

end
```

so, on your views :

```
<% = to_html(@song.lyrics) %>
```